# Java program to dump table as set of insert statements

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Is there a Java program to dump a table as a set of insert statements. I want to save state of a database table.

All I have is JDBC URL to DB which is located on network. Don't have Oracle installed thus no utilities and no SSH access either.

Looking for something similar to mysqldump or CSVWRITE in H2.

Comment: You can use Toad for MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: @RaviTiwari So one should spend a thousand dollars for generating a set of insert statements?

Comment: FYI Toad is also available as freeware for personal use.

Comment: Its a limited time trail. Could you give a link to a freeware version?

Comment: http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/default.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Are you a Java programmer? it shouldn't be difficult to create your own. Connect to Oracle, select from USER_TAB_COLUMNS to get column details, then select * and format into INSERTS using the column details

Comment: @ScottAllen That would be my last course of action unless I find something ready made.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31887249/32453

Answer (score 0):

To save a state of a table you have several options:

- Make a copy of the table data in another table.
- Export using the oracle EXP or EXPDMP utilities.
- Export into insert statements using external tools such as Toad,
  SQLDeveloper (free from Oracle), PLSQL Developer. Or look for an online example and/or write your own.

It all depends on how you want to use the copy of your data and how much it is. For quick testing work a copy of the data in another table works best for me. With a simple sql script your table is back to it's original state.